# coalesce columns for a uniqueid across multiple rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a kusto table in this format and I need to coalesce the value in columns into one row for a UniqueId. Could you give me some pointers?

| UniqueId | latencyForCall1 | latencyForCall2 | latencyForCall3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 100 |  |  |
| abcd |  | 120 |  |
| abcd |  |  | 240 |
| efgh | 130 |  |  |
| efgh |  | 110 |  |
| efgh |  |  | 310 |

| UniqueId | latencyForCall1 | latencyForCall2 | latencyForCall3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 100 | 120 | 240 |
| efgh | 130 | 110 | 310 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a summarize with [take_any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-any-aggfunction) aggregation function. If only one column is provided to it, it will attempt to use a non-null value.

Here is your example:

```
let T = datatable(UniqueId:string, latencyForCall1:long, latencyForCall2:long, latencyForCall3:long)
[
    "abcd", 100, long(null), long(null), 
    "abcd", long(null), 120, long(null), 
    "abcd", long(null), long(null), 240, 
    "efgh", 130, long(null), long(null), 
    "efgh", long(null), 110, long(null), 
    "efgh", long(null), long(null), 310, 
];
T
| summarize take_any(latencyForCall1), take_any(latencyForCall2), take_any(latencyForCall3) by UniqueId
```

| UniqueId | latencyForCall1 | latencyForCall2 | latencyForCall3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 100 | 120 | 240 |
| efgh | 130 | 110 | 310 |